# What are the advantages of other mutex wrapper libraries over std::mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, standard-library

The C++ standard library offers `std::mutex (lock, unlock, try_lock)` functionality, that can work within a multi-threaded environment.

Also I have heard talk about wrapper libraries (e.g. `Boost::mutex`) that provide, from what I can see, the same functionality (`lock, unlock, try_lock`).

My question is, what is the advantage of using such wrapper libraries over the standard one?

Comment: Historically, there is no real multi-threading in C++ before C++11 (even though many compilers and libraries provided it). Boost is an experimental ground, and the boost implementation of `mutex`, like that of `unordered_map`, was the basis for the integration in the Standard. So you could say that `std::mutex` is a refinement of `boost::mutex`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::mutex`, `std::thread` and other elements of the threading library are only available C++11. `boost::mutex` et al predate C++11. So the advantage is that you can use them if you don't have C++11 support.

Comment: Does pthread_mutex_unlock/lock in the pthread library provide similar functionality of std::mutex? And what is the difference?

Comment: @Kam the `std` stuff is stanadard and hence portable. The `boost` stuff is portable for many platforms. Pthreads us typically available only on *nix pr POSIX platforms

Answer (score 2):

While juanchopanza noted the most direct answer to the question (+1), one thing which `std::mutex` *introduces* over the types they wrap is use of exceptions. For most people/environments/needs, that would be considered a good thing. In some cases, you may not want exception dependence. In that case/environment, the `std::mutex` interfaces may not be an option or desirable.

Answer (score 2):

Some wrappers, like TBB and PPL, offer far more functionality than the Standard libraries.

1. Using pthreads/CreateThread yourself = writing your own `malloc`.
2. Using `std::thread` = `malloc`/`free`.
3. Using TBB/PPL = `std::vector`/`std::unique_ptr`.